# ¿Cómo puedo mantener un div en una posición determinada en un diseño responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Tengo un menú de navegación creado con bootstrap, dentro de dicho menú tengo una lista de links y una lista de íconos separados cada uno en dos div, el problema es que quiero que en todo momento de mi aplicación, independientemente de la resolución de la pantalla, la lista de links se muestre en el centro del menú de navegación y la lista de íconos se muestre a la derecha de mi menú de navegación. ¿Cómo podría manipular el css de dichos div para lograr eso?

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto align-items-center">
          <div class="align-links">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li> 
        </div>
          <div class="align-icons ml-auto justify-content-center">             
              <li class="nav-icon">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg "></i>
                </a>
              </li>  
              <li class="nav-icon">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
              </li> 
              <li class="nav-icon">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
          </li> 
        </div>                           
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Tal vez no te esté entendiendo bien pero al ejecutar el snippet que has puesto, ya sale todo centrado en el medio

Comment: Al ejecutar ese código en el navegador de una pc (min-width: 920px) no logro posicionar los <div> correspondientes a la lista de enlances y a la lista de íconos, al centro y a la derecha respectivamente.